# how to create the layout (attached as image) using UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

i am very much confused that how to create [image: this]

Using UITableViewController or another technique

**When user tap on any row it should expand**

Answer (score 1):

i will be easy using uitableview if u need any more help be clear bout the question

[image]

[image]

do u want in this way

Comment: when i tap on any row , it should expand

Comment: Take two arrays one for headers an keep it header section and set one method after click on section header call that method and show the cells of that particular header description

Answer (score 1):

You could create custom section headers with UIButton as the background for the header. The entire table will now comprise of headers only. By clicking on the button, you can add rows to the table which will give the expansion effect.

Answer (score 1):

see this tutorial. it is about drop-down tableview

https://github.com/floriankrueger/iOS-Examples--UITableView-Combo-Box/zipball/master

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread about it :
[Present a UITableView as drop-down list using the iOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294016/present-a-uitableview-as-drop-down-list-using-the-ios-sdk)

The dropdown-box is not default implemented in the IOS SDK

Comment: Ali, Please see the link I provided. There is explained how you can achieve such feature by using a button and drawing a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create collapse table view and set the background color property according to your  requirement. for collapse table view refer this

[1) Collapse TableView](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/40351-collapse-tableview-sections.html)
[2) Collapse Table](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240435/Reusable-collapsable-table-view-for-iOS)

check out the Apple library example [apple developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html)